# Embedded Google Doc Viewer Links no longer working

Tags: google-docs, google-document-viewer

For a long time, the following href worked to embed a google doc viewer to all sorts of document types (when used in association with something like fancybox):

```
var href = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + my_url + "&embedded=true";
```

However, as of a day or 2 ago this no longer works AND the support page at Google:

[Google Doc Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer)

Just redirects to the Google Docs homepage. (It used to provide a way to get the 'viewer link' by inputting your document's url.)

Anyone else running into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this suddenly started working again a few days ago.  The Google Doc Viewer link above still doesn't go to a dedicated page for the feature (it just redirects you to your Google Drive homepage), but the embedded doc viewer is again working.  I guess Google can giveth and taketh away at any time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that this was no longer working. It was an undocumented feature back when we started using it years ago, and Google has a habit of pulling the plug suddenly on entire divisions, so it wouldn't be a stretch to see them killing this feature.